# XNA Camera Scene size

Tags: c#, xna

I can't seem to figure this out. So the camera is looking into the world say at (0,0,0) positioned at (0,0,5.0f). Say the screen resolution is 800x600. Now, since the world's center is (0,0,0) what is the extreme point (say on the x-axis, the right side) that is visible to the camera?

What would the value be if the camera gets positioned at (0,0,50.0f)? Basically, how do I figure this out?

```
+-------------------+
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+---------+---------¤ <-- what's the x-value of this point?
|         |         |
|         |         |
|         |         |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Is this a perspective projection?

Comment: Yes it is. Basically, I am trying to draw/view within a certain bounds. For this to happen, I am going to need to calculate some variables, such as camera distance, scene size etc. This question is just to get me started. :)

Comment: Your question is "Whats the x value of this point" but you do know, that this is not really a point, its a ray. Do you mean the x value on the near plane? Also remember that, if you have a perspective projection, you have a view frustum not a, like in an orthogonal projection, a cuboid. Just wanted to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly you want to know the world space location of the point on the centre right of the screen?

That's actually pretty easy to do in XNA (thanks MS!), you can use the viewport class to "unproject" a screen space location to world space.

Basically every pixel drawn in your game goes through a few transformations to turn it in to a 2D image that can be drawn on our 2D displays, you can run those transformations backwards too and XNA has a method for this.

```
Vector3 screenLocation = new Vector3(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2, 0);
Vector3 worldLocation = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Unproject(screenLocation, camera.ProjectionMatrix, camera.ViewMatrix, camera.WorldMatrix);
```

edit:

if you're trying to see if an object within the cameras view so it can be drawn, you can use the bounding frustum to test.

```
BoundingFrustum frustum = new BoundingFrustum(camera.WorldViewProjectionMatrix);
```

frustum contains a method named Intersects that has quite a few overrides to test if things like bounding boxes are inside the frustum.

Comment: Man that was patronising.. sorry :D

Comment: Oh hmm... interesting! I guess that would be one way to do it. Is it possible to get the same results without going through the projection?

Comment: not really, the camera viewing the world can be placed at any location and at any angle, what you're trying to get is a point in space that's closest to the pixel you're viewing it with.

Comment: If you change the 0 for the z value of screen space to 1, it will get the point on the right middle of the screen as far away from the screen as the camera can see.

Comment: You don't have to do each point yourself if you're trying to cull objects that can't be seen, once again XNA does it all for you with the BoundingFrustum class

BoundingFrustum frustum = new BoundingFrustum(camera.WorldViewProjectionMatrix);

You can use it's frustum.Intersects(..) method to find out if other bounding volumes are inside it.